# Functions wont work after reopen a modal

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_roles" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="../assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif" alt="" class="loading"><span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Loading... </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I call it:

```
<button class="btn btn-default font-grey-mint" href="my_data.php" type="button" data-target="#modal_roles" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-shield">my modal
</button>
```

When I open the modal, I see the spinner for a short time, then the content from `my_data.php` is shown.

This content is the following HTML and JS Code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title font-grey-mint"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> '.T::MYPROFIL_36.' </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable hide" id="msg_box_role">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <div id="msg_box_role_text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="part_content">
            '.$cont.'
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-close"></i> '.T::BASELAY_7.'</button>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$("[data-toggle=confirmation]").confirmation({ btnOkClass: "btn btn-sm btn-success", btnCancelClass: "btn btn-sm btn-danger"}); 

function shortwork() { 
    var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-id");
    var jobid = $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-job-id");  
    $.ajax({
        url: "my_data.php?step="+jobid+"&ds="+id,
        type: "PUT",
        success: function(result) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(result);
            if(res=="ok"){
                eval(res.js)
            }else{
                eval(res.js)
            } 
        }
    });
}
$(".shortwork").on("click", shortwork );

$(".submitForm").on("click", ajaxsubmit);

function ajaxsubmit() {
   var formid = $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-formid"); 
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_rollenverwaltung.php",
        data: $("#"+formid).serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            var res = $.parseJSON(result);
            if(res.code=="ok") { 
                if(res.msg.length > 0 ) {
                    $("#msg_box_role").removeClass("hide");
                    $("#msg_box_role").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#msg_box_role").addClass("alert-info");
                    $("#msg_box_role_text").text(res.msg);
                }

                eval(res.js)
            } else {
                if(res.msg.length > 0 ) {
                    $("#msg_box_role").removeClass("hide, alert-info");
                    $("#msg_box_role").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#msg_box_role_text").text(res.msg);
                }
                alert("NICHT OK");
                eval(res.js); 
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure:");
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

If I open the modal for the first time, all is ok.
If I close the modal no function will work again.
What I do wrong at this point?

Comment: Can you add the code where you open/close the modal?

Comment: i've update the code, you can see it  inside <div class="modal-content">